# How can I bet against oil in the long term?

Tags: investing, options, investment-strategies

I want to bet against oil over a long term period (5-10 years, let's say). What is the best way for me to go about this, i.e what should I purchase and how?

Comment: Exactly what bet are you trying to make? That oil will raise in value by a specific date? Lower in value? Or that oil companies will go up (or down) in value by a specific date?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I want to bet that the value of oil will fall by a specific date. Betting that oil companies will go down by a specific date also works for me.

Comment: Perhaps you could also consider going long on those commodities that are negatively co-related with oil..?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult/impossible for individuals to carry long term options in the 5-10 year range like you're asking.  Personally I wanted to go long oil, so I bought a couple of oil ETFs.  You could find a "short oil" etf and hold that.  These funds have access to the long term options you're looking for.  The fund buys a stack of those options then you buy shares of the fund.  Stay away from long term holding an "ultra short" or "3x short" or other highly leveraged short funds.

Be sure to research what the fund actually holds.  Don't blindly trust the name of the fund or the highlights of the prospectus.

Comment: While highly leveraged funds are even worse, inverse etfs still have many of the same terrible characteristics for long term investing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_exchange-traded_fund